# Java String representation of an Object handling arrays

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I have an object of type Object, and I want to return a String representation of it using the *toString()* method, except if it is an array, I want to return Arrays.toString() of the object (I don't need a deepToString).

I thought about using this :

```
public static String getValueAsString(Object value){
    if(value != null && value.getClass().isArray()){
        if(value instanceof Object[])
            return Arrays.toString((Object[])value);
        else if(value instanceof int[])
            return Arrays.toString((int[])value);
        else ...
    }else
        return String.valueOf(value);
}
```

The problem is that I can detect it is an array, but I have to handle all the different primitive array ...

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this ? using core methods or reflection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the generic [`Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) class to iterate **any** array like this:

```
private static String toStr(Object o) {
    if (o == null || !o.getClass().isArray()) {
        return String.valueOf(o);

    } else {
        final int len = Array.getLength(o);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder('[');
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            sb.append(Array.get(o, i)).append(i + 1 < len ? ", " : "");

        return sb.append(']').toString();
    }
}
```

---

### Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(toStr(new int[] {1,2,3}));
    System.out.println(toStr(new double[] {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}));
    System.out.println(toStr(new Object[] {null, 7, 8.0}));
    System.out.println(toStr("Hello World!"));
}
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[null, 7, 8.0]
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflexion to call the right Arrays.toString method on your array, like the following:

```
public static String toStr(Object a) {
        if (a == null)
              return "null"; //like String.valueOf(null);

        Class<?> clazz = a.getClass();
        if (clazz.isArray()) {
            if (Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
                clazz = Object[].class;
            try {
                final Method m = Arrays.class.getMethod("toString", clazz);
                return (String) m.invoke(null, a);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } else {
            return a.toString();
        }
    }
```

Which works with primitive arrays as well as object arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toStr(new int[]{2,4}));
        System.out.println(toStr(new double[]{2L,3L}));
        System.out.println(toStr(new String[]{"a","b", null}));
        System.out.println(toStr(new Integer[]{2,3}));
        System.out.println(toStr(new char[]{'a','r'}));
    }
```

Output:

```
[2, 4]
[2.0, 3.0]
[a, b, null]
[2, 3]
[a, r]
```

Comment: I would suggest to use the `Array` class instead of reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache Commons lang -  [ArrayUtils.toString()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html)

```
public static String toString(Object array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently used [this blogpost](http://binkley.blogspot.nl/2007/08/recursive-tostring.html) as a basis to create a flexible, recursive toString method.